# If $|z-2|=1$, what are the maximum and minimum values $|z+i|$ can have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If $|z-2|=1$, what are the maximum and minimum values $|z+i|$ can take?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I corrected the question already.

Comment: Drawing a picture is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that
$$\{z+i\in\mathbb{C}:|z-2|=1\}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-(2+i)|=1\}=\text{circle of radius 1 centered at }2+i$$
**Hint:** Now draw a line from the origin (that is, $0$) to $2+i$, the center of the circle, and then keep drawing until it passes through the circle. What are the points of intersection?